# converting string variable which contains date '10/13/2019 12:16:58 PM' to mysql date formate ('yyyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss tt") vb.net to mysql formate

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, datetime, timestamp

converting string variable which contains date  '10/13/2019 12:16:58 PM'  to MySQL date formate ('yyyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss tt") vb.net to MySQL format

I have variable which contain date value as `10/13/2019 12:16:58 PM`

I want to convert it into MySQL format as `('yyyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss tt')`

how to do it in vb.net 
any help

I have searched net but not worked,
I want to convert just variable value

```
sqlquerym = "Select * 
             FROM registration  
             where pcname='" & strHostName & "' and ip='" & strIPAddress & "' and timestap='" & lbltimestap.Text & "' and serialnumber='" & sysserial & "' 

             ORDER BY id limit 1"
```

where lbltimestap.Text contains string value of date as '10/13/2019 12:16:58 PM' but in mysql table it is stored as 2019-10-13 12:16:58 so no results shown

Comment: Look into using the `STR_TO_DATE()` MySQL function.  I can't answer because I don't know statements in VB.

Comment: In order to do what you ask, you would need to convert the `String` you have to a `Date` and then convert that to a `String`.  That would be the wrong thing to do.  What you should do is the first half, i.e. convert the `String` to a `Date`, and then use a parameter to pass that binary `Date` value to the database directly.  The `String` to `Date` conversion can be done using `Date.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact` and you can learn about using parameters with ADO.NET in many places.

Comment: That said, you should pretty much NEVER be using a `Label` as an input source.  A `Label` is for display, not data storage.  Where did the value displayed in the `Label` come from?  That original value is probably what you should be using, especially if it is a `Date`.

Comment: Dim datee As String
        datee = "10/13/2019 1:47:54 PM"
        MsgBox(DateTime.ParseExact(datee, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing))
                                                                                                                          
 an error happend                                                                                                                          
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: an i imports system.formatexception                                 but now shows error as                         An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Select * FROM registration where pcname='786-PC' and ip='192.168.0.101' and timestap=STR_TO_DATE( '10/13/2019 1:47:54','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') and serialnumber='..CN744318390D41.' ORDER BY id limit 1
    ................... this also does not works

Comment: What is the datatype of the timestap column in the database?

Comment: HH refers to a 24 hour clock which is not what you are using since you have an AM PM designation. Lower case h and hh refers to a 12 hour clock.

Comment: Wow! Not a single mention of using parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Tim Biegelsen, instead of doing the conversion in VB, you can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the date string to a MySQL date, as follows:

```
sqlquerym = 
    "Select * FROM registration  where "
    & "pcname='" & strHostName & "' "
    & "and ip='" & strIPAddress & "' "
    & "and timestap=STR_TO_DATE('%d/%m/%Y %r', '" & lbltimestap.Text & "') "
    & "and serialnumber='" & sysserial & "' "
    & "ORDER BY id limit 1"
```

Details:

```
%d: Day of the month, numeric (01..31)
%m: Month, numeric (01..12)
%Y: Year, numeric, four digits
%r: Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpest way is to convert your variable to a date

and then use

```
dataRow("timecolumn") = datevariable.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```